# How can i update dataGridview After editing values c#?

Tags: c#, sql

i have a a table **("UserPr")** and i display the data to gridview , so when i edit values of one cell directly from the datagridview **like:** changing chexkbox**("canShow")** value from true or false at one row , the changes updates all rows values to the same value and the for the column which the value changed.
[image]
here is my code :-

```
 private void button4_Click(object sender,EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                int UseID = Convert.ToInt32( TXT_ID.Text);
                Boolean CanShow = dataGridView2.Rows[0].Cells[5].Value.Equals(true || false);
                Boolean CanOpen = dataGridView2.Rows[0].Cells[6].Value.Equals(true || false);
                Boolean CanAdd = dataGridView2.Rows[0].Cells[7].Value.Equals(true || false);
                Boolean CanEdit = dataGridView2.Rows[0].Cells[8].Value.Equals(true || false);
                Boolean CanDelete = dataGridView2.Rows[0].Cells[9].Value.Equals(true || false);
                Boolean CanPrint = dataGridView2.Rows[0].Cells[10].Value.Equals(true || false);

                if (TXT_ID.Text != "")
                {
                    foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView2.Rows)
                    {
                        string constring = @"Data Source = MOHAMEDTHRWAT20\SQLEXPRESS; Initial Catalog = SharpControl; Integrated Security = True";
                        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(constring))
                        {
                            String updateData = "UPDATE UserPr SET CanShow=@CanShow,CanOpen=@CanOpen,CanAdd=@CanAdd,CanEdit=@CanEdit,CanDelete=@CanDelete,CanPrint=@CanPrint WHERE UseID='" + UseID + "'";
                            SqlCommand update = new SqlCommand(updateData, con);
                            {
                                con.Open();
                                update.Parameters.Add("@CanShow", SqlDbType.Bit).Value= CanShow;
                                update.Parameters.Add("@CanOpen", SqlDbType.Bit).Value= CanOpen;
                                update.Parameters.Add("@CanAdd", SqlDbType.Bit).Value = CanAdd;
                                update.Parameters.Add("@CanEdit", SqlDbType.Bit).Value = CanEdit;
                                update.Parameters.Add("@CanDelete", SqlDbType.Bit).Value = CanDelete;
                                update.Parameters.Add("@CanPrint", SqlDbType.Bit).Value = CanPrint;
                                update.ExecuteNonQuery();
                                con.Close();
                            }  
                        }
                    }
                    //updateaut();

                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

I have a project like that.
The way I did, I cleared the datagridview, than I filled with data.

```
private void ClearDataGridView()
    {
        dgv.Rows.Clear();
    }

public static void AddDataToGridView(System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView dataGrid, string column1, string column2)
    {

        dataGrid.Rows.Add(column1, column2);
    }
```

The values from the columns I would fetch from database source